# while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ when selection multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating this  search function with PHP, javascript and mysql.

This code is working like it should. I type in some data in a a html search box, which sends the %keyword% to this PHP function, which returns the data as I want.

```
$query = "SELECT id,fornavn,efternavn,adresse,postnr,city,tlf,kon,email,fodselsdag FROM kunde WHERE email LIKE '%$keyword%' OR fornavn LIKE '%$keyword%'";


$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

if($result){
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)!=0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        listings($row['fornavn'],$row['efternavn'], $row['email'],$row['adresse'],$row['tlf'],$row['postnr'],$row['city'],$row['fodselsdag'],$row['id'],$bartype);
    }
```

I have another TABLE where the id from the SQL above is stored in relation to another ID. The table looks like this:

```
Table name: vip
Colmns: id, brugerid, barid
```

Now I want to be customize the SQL in the code above, so it only picks data that also has a relation in the vip table.

I do it this way:

```
SELECT *, kunde.id as kundeid FROM kunde,vip WHERE  vip.brugerid = kunde.id AND vip.barid =1 AND email LIKE '%$keyword%' OR fornavn LIKE '%$keyword%';
```

Actually whenever I add more than one table, the php code stops working..  any idea why this is happening? And how I can achieve this?

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: 1. has `$keyword` been escaped properly? If not, your code is wide open to a SQL injection hack.

Comment: It will be a closed system with only a few users. But any suggestions in securing it will be very appreciated

Comment: 2. Be aware that using a `LIKE` clause with a wildcard percent sign at both ends can make your queries very slow. (this depends, of course, on the amount of data in the table, but for a large DB, it's generally a bad idea)

Comment: it's not just deliberate attacks that you need to protect against. If it isn't escaped properly, you'll also have problems if `$keyword` contains characters such as an apostrophe or a percent sign.

Comment: Thank you I will look into it when the main problem is solved. Any ideas on that?

Comment: it stops working because php hates you for writing entire sql queries on a single line.

Comment: Look up the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function, or better yet, look up parameterised queries (eg using the mysqli_prepare function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

```
SELECT *, kunde.id as kundeid FROM kunde INNER JOIN vip ON (vip.brugerid = kunde.id) WHERE  kunde.id=1 AND email LIKE '%$keyword%' OR fornavn LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

Comment: Oh my god! You just saved my day! Incredible!

Answer (score 0):

I see unnecessary comma here: `FROM kunde,vip, WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks that was a typo here on stackoverflow. The main problem is using the while loop in my headline, when selecting more than one table in the sql

Comment: OK, but please elaborate on a problem? Does your code enter the loop? Does it execute at least once? Maybe it executes infinitely? "Problem with loop" is not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Also, consider using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) in your future developement since it's a more consistent interface for accessing databases, unlike mysqli and mysql_query.